# For $f$ analytic on $\mathbb{D}$, if $f(\mathbb{D}) \subset \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \Re(z) < 0\}$ and $f(0) = -1$, prove an inequality of $|f(z)|$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Old complex analysis qual question, here.  The unit disk $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1\}$ is denoted $\mathbb{D}$:

> For $f$ non-constant and analytic on $\mathbb{D}$, if $f(\mathbb{D}) \subset \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \Re(z) < 0\}$ and $f(0) = -1$, prove that $$\frac{1 - |z|}{1 + |z|} \le |f(z)| \le \frac{1 + |z|}{1 - |z|}$$

I feel like I'm not seeing something obvious here.  I can't compose this with some function from the RMT, since the image is not necessarily simply connected...  Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(z)=\frac {f(z)+1} {f(z)-1}$. Then $g$ maps $\mathbb D$ into itself and vanishes at $0$. By Schwartz Lemma $|g(z)|\leq |z|$. This gives $|f(z)|-1 \leq |f(z)+1| =|g(z)| |f(z)-1| \leq|z|(|f(z)|+1)$. From this you get the right hand inequality. Now $\frac 1 f$ satisfies the hypothesis too and applying the right hand inequality to this function gives theleft hand inequality.

Comment: I'm not seeing how you could have arrived at your second inequality...

Comment: Are you ask how I got $|f(z)|-1 \leq |z|(|f(z)|+1)$? I am just using the inequalities $|f(z)+1| \geq |f(z)|-1$ and $|f(z)-1| \leq |f(z)|+1$.

Comment: @MöbiusDickus I have added  some more steps. I hope the proof is clear now.